# CQ5 Dialog.xml - how to insert a paragraph?

Tags: aem

Most of the text in my dialog.xml is labels for form inputs.

Is there a way to have just a plain paragraph that offers the user some explanation?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `label` xtype:

```
<mylabel
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="My label"
    html="Some description text in &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;"
    xtype="label"/>
```

As you can see, you can even use simple tags within the html property like `<b>` and `<i>`. Of course the brackets escaped as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: The `label` xtype is also a great option. The out of the box styling on the text for `label` is larger and darker than `displayfield`. In addition, you can use `hideLabel="{Boolean}true"` to have your paragraph span the label column as well.

Comment: If you want it to look exactly like any other field descriptions, you can add `cls="x-form-item-description"` and `style="display: block;"`. One downside of this method is that it renders a semantically useless `<label>` tag. Unfortunately `displayfield` does not seem to respect `hideLabel="{Boolean}true"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `displayfield` xtype. Read the [docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.DisplayField) for the CQ5 Widget API `CQ.Ext.form.DisplayField`. Here is an example:

```
<instructions
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Instructions"
    fieldDescription="Insert instructions for your authors here."
    xtype="displayfield" />
```

You can use long paragraphs and you can insert HTML by using character entities. For example:

```
This will bold &lt;strong&gt;this text&lt;/strong&gt;.
```